# Nothing I Do Will Disable Access Warnings

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've tried all of the suggestions....

- Access Options, Confirm settings for action queries
- VBA SetWarnings off and back on
- The db is in a trusted folder location

No matter what I do I still get warnings / confirmation popups in Access when running my forms and macros. What else could be overriding my settings?

Is it possible for group policies to override my settings? How do I find those policy settings?

We have a process that we run in Access 2x monthly, and it takes too long because the users have to click Yes on all the popups. I've tried the obvious tricks, but nothing prevents these confirmation popups.

Comment: What are the warnings?  Have you tried "Currentdb.Execute" instead of "doCmd.RunSQL"?

Comment: SetWarnings has always worked flawlessly for me.  Have you tried importing your objects into a new DB?  There might be some funky corruption going on that's blocking that command.

Comment: I can try both suggestions. Might be a day before I can, but I'll let you know. The warnings are the usual "you are about to do xxxxx, are you sure?" that pop up when running any query or delete that will edit records or remove a table, etc.

Comment: Might need some specifics here... like some code you've written that is triggering the warnings. I could only give speculative/general answers at the moment. As @OpiesDad says though, if it is sql written in vba that's triggering the warnings, assign your sql string to a string variable like `strSql` and then execute the sql with `CurrentDb.Execute strSql`.

Comment: Docmd.setwarnings False should take care of those. Are you definitely setting them OFF at the start of the entire process, and switching them back ON at the end. be careful you're not inadvertently switching them back ON in one of your sub's or macros.

Comment: Changing to the Currentdb.Execute command did the trick. Thank You OpiesDad. It's been a long while since I messed with VB in any form, so this is a good way to start refreshing. Appreciate the other suggestions, but I had already tried all of the obvious things. 

How do I mark your reply as the answer?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.  You are probably having one of the other issues that the commenters are stating, though, such as a corrupted database or another procedure turning the warnings back on.  There is no reason the setwarnings statement shouldn't work.  The Currentdb.Execute method always suppresses the warnings, and, in my opinion, is a better idea anyways, but this won't fix a corrupted database, which could, eventually, become unusable.  I'd recommend copying everything to a new database just to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VBA to execute SQL, then try to use:

```
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

instead of

```
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

where strSQL represents the SQL statement you are trying to execute.

This automatically suppresses the normal warnings from running a query, but will still give you other errors, such as when the SQL is invalid.  You can also use this to get certain items from the query, such as the amount of records affected by the query, that you otherwise cannot get from the docmd statement.